# Not able to understand the function of this return statement, without it a runtime error occurs

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

In the `if` statement of the `bstcreate()` function below, if I remove the `return` statement a runtime error occurs.  Why is that?

Shouldn't the process go to the `while` statement even without the `return` statement, because all the statements would have been executed?

Here is the code below:

```c
struct Node{
    struct Node *lchild;
    int data;
    struct Node *rchild;

}*root=NULL;

void bstcreate(int key)
{
    struct Node*t=root;
    struct Node*p,*r=NULL;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        p = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        p->data = key;
        p->lchild = p->rchild = NULL;
        root = p;
        return;
    }

    while(t)
    {
        r=t;
        if(key<t->data)
        {
            t=t->lchild;
        }
        else
        {
            t=t->rchild;
        }
    }
    p = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p->data = key;
    p->lchild = p->rchild = NULL;

    if(r->data>key)
    {
        r->lchild=p;
    }
    else
    {
        r->rchild=p;
    }
}
```

Comment: What debugger do you have available to you? Step through the code with your debugger and when the program crashes, see what the values of the relevant variables are.

Comment: Well, if you remove that `return` statement, you are changing the fundamental, core logic of the function. If with the `return` statement in place the logic was correct, then without it the function's logic is no longer correct, and things will not work right. So, what exactly are you unclear about?

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what the `while` loop is doing. You should explain it to them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik im not able to understand the role of blank return statement in the 1st place. Im trying to create a bst by insertion and unable to understand that why without the return statement the code is not able to enter the while loop.

Comment: The while loop in the code is to find the place for the element(key)  to be inserted

Comment: Since without the `return` statement `t` will obviously be `NULL`, of course the code will not enter the `while` loop. That's very obvious, and that's not the reason for the crash. Take this as an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger so you can run this function line by line, and see exactly what's happening, where exactly this function crashes, and why. Knowing how to use a debugger to figure these things out is something that every C++ developer ***must*** know. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds about right. Now your rubber duck wants to know why you would bother executing the while loop if the list was empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is empty, `bstcreate()` sets `root` to a new `Node`, and then is expected to exit immediately since there is nothing else to do.  The `return` statement performs that exit.  Since the function is declared as returning `void`, there is no need to provide a value to `return`.

`t` is initialized to `root` and `r` is initialized to `NULL`.  If you remove the `return` statement, and `root` is `NULL` upon entry, then `t` is initially `NULL` causing the `while` loop to be skipped, and then a crash occurs when accessing members of `r` because `r` is still `NULL` since the loop did not assign `r` to point anywhere.